# std::vector ctor compiles outside of class, but not inside?

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

Why does the `explicit vector (size_type n)` form work outside of a class but not inside?
This compiles:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec_(3); // set capacity to 3
    return 0;
}
```

But not this:

```
#include <vector>

class C {
public:
    std::vector<int> vec_(3); // set capacity to 3
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}

g++ --std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra  -g a.cpp
a.cpp:5:27: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
a.cpp:5:27: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

Why? :(

Comment: That's not how you initialize data members inside a class. Who taught you that?

Comment: Because you call member constructors via the class constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be:

```
class C {
public:
    C() : vec_(3) {} // set capacity to 3 in constructor initialization list
    std::vector<int> vec_;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want is:

```
class C {
public:
    std::vector<int> vec_;
    C() : vec_(3) { }
};
```

This will control how `vec_` is constructed when you construct a `C` object.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's not a valid syntax in C++. The correct way would be:

```
#include <vector>

class C {
public:
    std::vector<int> vec_;

public:
    // You add a constructor and initialize member data there:
    C () : vec_(3) {}
};
```

There are other ways to do it, but this is the most widely used and accessible one.